# Imagemagick 6.9.1-7 won't convert psd to any format (Yosemite)

Tags: imagemagick, psd

When I run this:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert ~/desktop/myImage.psd ~/desktop/myImage.jpg
```

I get this error:

```
convert: no images defined `/Users/User/desktop/myImage.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3230.
```

Here's my convert -version:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-7 Q16 x86_64 2015-07-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png tiff xml zlib
```

I've tried at least 4 different psd files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 6.9.1-8 to address the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am one on the developers of ImageMagick and this version contains a bug in the PSD reader. We are aware of this bug and it will be fixed in 6.9.1-8.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the answer. Was beginning to lose my mind. Any idea when that will be released?

Comment: We are trying to publish the release this weekend.

Comment: Just upgraded to 6.9.1-8 and it seems fixed.  Thanks!